# How to fix fast scrolling in Ubuntu 20.04.3 running in hyper-v?

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics, scrolling

I am using Ubuntu via hyper-v.. two finger scroll via touchpad is too sensitive (ie) it is too fast for page scroll. I am also not getting touchpad options in settings.

I tried to install and reboot, but no luck

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and I ran **xinput list** I got below output.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xrdpMouse                                 id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xrdpKeyboard                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

How to fix scroll speed?

Comment: What hardware make and model.

Comment: HP EliteBook x360, Intel I7 @David